# Changing directory 'cd' using bash

Tags: bash

I want to change the directory in linux using bash file. Below is the code snippet used.

```
#!/bin/bash
alias proj="cd /home/prag/Downloads"
```

But on running the bash file there is not response, i.e. it stays in the same directory. Why is it so.? Why doesn't alias work here or should I do something different.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running the bash file won't work as the change to the current working directory stays within the script (as it is a separate process to the process that gives you your command prompt - bash).

Add the alias to your ~/.bash_aliases or ~/.bashrc file (former is preferable, latter might be quicker if the former doesn't exist) and then it should work.

Comment: thanks for clearing that. can you help me in writing the alias as am new to bash.

Comment: You've already written it. Just copy 'alias proj="cd /home/prag/Downloads"' into your .bash_aliases or .bashrc file. Save it then close your terminal and re-open it and your command should work.

Comment: @pragadheesh: If this has answered your question, could you mark it as the answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Each process has its own current directory. When you start a bash script, and it changes its current directory and then exists, this has no effect on the parent process (i.e. the shell from which you launches the script).

Instead of running `./script.sh`, try `source ./script.sh` (or `. ./script.sh` for short).

Also, defining an `alias` for `cd` won't on its own change the directory. I assume you actually invoke the alias somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you want to write a bash script that will cd to another directory?

Then why use an alias?  Just use the "cd" command!

Comment: For speed. If you're going into that directory a lot then it makes sense to alias it. I have a little program and bash_aliases entry I use that lets me store terminal 'bookmarks'. I simply type 'pj foo' and it takes me to the directory stored against that name.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your script is executed in a new shell-process when you call it like `./cd.sh`.
So your script would change the directory in that subshell, and when your script exits control returns to your previous shell.

You can call your script like that `. cd.sh` - this executes the script in the current shell and the cd-command works.